# How to login to skype using java programatically?

Tags: java, api, authentication, skype

I'm currently working on a project. I need to know how we can login to web.Skype.com using java, but programmatically.

I have a list of user names and passwords, and what I have to do is to login using these credentials on Skype.

Here is summary of my project:

This project is an asynchronous multithreaded skype autoresponder for windows desktop which utilizes (emulates) http://web.skype.com. the purpose of this program is for it to hold "conversations" with real people in real time who send contact requests or instant messages to the "bot" skype accounts it controls. this is only an autoresponder which responds to incoming contact requests and instant messages and does not add contacts from a database and initiate conversations with them, though i may request this feature to be added in at a later date. please make yourself familiar with web.skype.com or a github api which utilizes it. study the packets/headers, etc. as for this job you will essentially be creating a new lightweight skype client which controls many different skype accounts simultaneously through it.

Comment: do you have any sample code you've tried?

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place?

Comment: No , i do not have

Answer (score 6):

You Can Use  selenium web driver To get into Skype Here I am Writing The Code Below Which Will Help You To Get Through The Login process Using Java

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Skype {
static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
public static void main(String[] args) {

driver.get("https://login.skype.com/login?     client_id=578134&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.skype.com%2F");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
element.sendKeys("");
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
element1.sendKeys("");
WebElement signup = driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
signup.click();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Which API are you using? Have you looked through and tried this one:
https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api

Here is a really great tutorial of how to implement the above api in a custom made application and successfully connect to skype:

http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/10543/skype-java-api-tutorial

I recommend you have a look at that one. It seems pretty well explained!

Comment: I am using java 'skype-java-api-1.5-sources.jar'
i searched through the internet, but no success.I am unable to find the solution.I have to login to Skype through a java program.